# Star UML: how to add get/set properties

Tags: uml, staruml

I have started using Star UML application and its great. Is there a way to add get/set functions and foward/reverse engineer the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an operator then set the stereotype to CSharpProperty.

Example:

1. Right-click the class in the Model Explorer
2. Select Add -> Operation
3. In the property pane add the CSharpProperty stereotype.
4. Add a "return" parameter (right-click the new operation and select Add -> return)
5. Set the Type to the property type (e.g. int, string, etc.)
6. Set the DiretionKind to Return

The above steps should produce C# code with both an accessor and modifier when StarUML generates the code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install a tool named "Generate Getters and Setters".

1. Open the StarUML and select **Tools** -> **Extension Manager...**
2. Search "**Generate Getters and Setters**" and install it
3. Reload the StarUML
4. Select attributes or classes first and then select **Tools** -> **Generate Getters Setters**
   (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)

[staruml-gettersetter in GitHub](https://github.com/niklauslee/staruml-gettersetter)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is an easy way for automation in generating getters and setters.
The development of StarUML stopped 4 years ago. An alternative would be nice.